# getattr en generadores de pony orm

Tags: python, ponyorm

Tengo el siguiente problema (cuya respuesta temo que sea que no lo soporta). He comprobado que esta sentencia se ejecuta sin problemas:

```
res = tuple(Cliente.select(lambda c: c.nombre == "Pepe"))
```

Pero mi problema es que *nombre* está dentro de una variable, así que he intentado lo siguiente para probar:

```
res = tuple(Cliente.select(lambda c: getattr(c, "nombre") == "Pepe"))
```

Esto, en cambio, me devuelve un error `TypeError: getattr(c, 'nombre')`. No me parece que con ceptualmente haya un error así que creo que, simplemente, no lo soporta pony-orm. ¿Sabe alguno algo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualmente Pony ORM no permite el uso de `getattr`. Queremos añadir esta función en el futuro. Esto es un poco no trivial, porque Pony ORM se traduce a SQL generador de una sola vez, y luego se almacena en caché el resultado de la traducción. Al utilizar `getattr`, diferente nombre del atributo produce diferentes consultas. Así que tendremos que añadir el nombre de atributo en una clave de caché. En este momento se puede solucionar el problema mediante el uso de consulta textual:

```python
attr = 'nombre'
res = tuple(Cliente.select('lambda c: c.%s == "Pepe"' % attr))
```

La consulta textual está funcionando de la misma manera como una consulta habitual, puede pasar parámetros a la misma:

```python
attr = 'nombre'
x = 'Pepe'
res = tuple(Cliente.select('lambda c: c.%s == x' % attr))
```

Usted necesita tener cuidado de no sustituir los datos definidos por el usuario directamente en la cadena de consulta, porque hay un riesgo de inyección SQL.

I Google tradujo este texto, espero que parece correcta.